# Find sub-string in list

Tags: python-2.7, arraylist

I'm trying to exclude a list of strings from another list. I don't want to use external modules if at all possible.

```
things = [
"Hotdog1",
"Doc2",
"Hotdog12",
"Doc3",
"Spoon2"
]

exclude = ["Hotdog", "Monkey", "Jam"] # list of things to exclude

for n in things:
  if not n in exclude:
    print n

# >>> "Doc2", "Doc3", "Spoon2" # should be this
```

Only things is an object and I can't use startstwith() as as you can tell the above code doesn't work. What's the most pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it can be done in more easier way. I was missing Python lol :P

```
    class FilterThings(object):
    def __init__(self, things, exclude):
        """

        :param (list) things:
        :param (list)(str) exclude:
        """
        self.things = things
        self.exclude = exclude

    def filter_exclude_things(self):
        filtered = []
        for thing in self.things:
            if not self.check_if_excluded(thing):
                filtered.append(thing)
        return filtered

    def check_if_excluded(self, thing):
        """

        :param (str) thing:
        :return (boolean): True if thing in exclude list else False
        """
        for ex_thing in self.exclude:
            if len(thing) > len(ex_thing):
                result = thing.find(ex_thing)
            else:
                result = ex_thing.find(thing)
            if result > -1:
                break
        else:
            return False
        return True


ft = FilterThings(things1, exclude1)
print ft.filter_exclude_things()
# OP ['Doc2', 'Doc3', 'Spoon2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ! 
I am also attach the screenshot of the output .

```
things = [
"Hotdog1",
"Doc2",
"Hotdog12",
"Doc3",
"Spoon2"
]

exclude = ["Hotdog", "Monkey", "Jam"] # list of things to exclude

def find(t):
  for i in range(0,len(exclude)):
    if t.find(exclude[i])!=-1:
      return False
    return True


for n in range(0,len(things)):
  if find(things[n]):
    print(things[n])
```

[image]

Comment: The runtime of this method is `O(n^2*m)`. I’m sure you could do better than that?

Comment: In fact, there is a way to do it that is `O(m+n)` ;)